# Developer authentication in php error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I am a developer trying to connect to a server in PHP. Here is my code for server developer authentication:

```
    <?php
  require 'aws.phar';

   use Aws\CognitoIdentity\CognitoIdentityClient;
   use Aws\Sts\StsClient;
   use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
   use Aws\S3\S3Client;

   $identityClient = CognitoIdentityClient::factory(array(
    'version' => 'latest',

    'region'  => 'ap-northeast-1'
    ));

  $idResp = $identityClient->getId(array(
    'AccountId' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    'IdentityPoolId' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
'Logins' => array(
  'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr' => 'login.blupinch.app'
)
   ));

 $identityId = $idResp["IdentityId"];
 $tokenResp = $identityClient->getOpenIdToken(array(
'IdentityId' => $identityId,
'Logins' => array(
 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr' => 'login.blupinch.app'
)
));

$token = $tokenResp["Token"];


$stsClient = StsClient::factory(array(
'region'  => 'us-east-1',
'version' => '2011-06-15'
));
    $stsResp = $stsClient->assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(array(
     'RoleArn' =>'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/Cognito_appAuth_Role',
  'RoleSessionName' => 'App', // you need to give the session a name
  'WebIdentityToken' => $token
 ));


 $credentials = new Credentials(
    $stsResp['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    $stsResp['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    $stsResp['Credentials']['SessionToken']
   );

   $s3Client = new S3Client([
  'version' => '2006-03-01',
  'region'  => 'us-east-1',
  'credentials' => $credentials 
   ]);
```

The code is quite elaborate, as is the following error message which I'm getting. I'm having trouble making sense of this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception           
'Aws\CognitoIdentity\Exception\CognitoIdentityException' with message     
'Error executing "GetId" on "https://cognito-identity.ap-northeast-     
1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: 
Client error: 
`POST https://cognito-   identity.ap-  northeast-1.amazonaws.com` resulted  
in a `400 Bad Request` response:   
{"__type":"ValidationException","message":
"1 validation error detected: 
Value '{cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr=login (truncated...) 
ValidationException (client): 
1 validation error detected: 
Value '{cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr=login.blupinch.app}' at 'logins'      
failed to satisfy constraint: 
Map keys must satisfy constraint: 
[Member    must have length less than or equal to 128, Member must have   
length    greater than or equal to 1, Member must satisfy regular expression    
pattern: [\w._/-]+] - {"__type":
"ValidationException","message":
"1     validation error detected: 
Value '{cognito-    identity.amazonaws.com:amr=login.blupinch.app}' at        
'logins' failed to    satisfy constraint: 
Map keys must satisfy constraint: 
[Mem in    phar:///home/ubuntu/aws.phar/Aws/WrappedHttpHandler.php on
```

I believe the error is related to the value for the key `cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr`. So I'm wondering, what should I set the value for that key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the backend server does not need to call GetId or GetOpenIdToken API. From your server you need to call [GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html) API of Amazon Cognito. For the logins map, key should be the developer provider name you have specified in the Amazon Cognito Console for this identity pool, the value should be a unique user identifier of the user which has authenticated with your server from the native app. Cognito will return an identityId associated with that username and a OpenId Connect Token to your backend and it should be passed back to the app.

I would highly encourage you to follow our [blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en) and the [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/), it explains this flow in depth. As always, if you have any questions please feel free to ask.

Thanks.

Comment: In the cognito console, I hav created a custom provider by clicking custom tab, I gave a name there log.blupinch.app. So this is the key? and value is unique identifier, does that mean a username of user? finally are you saying this?    'log.blupinch.app' => <username>?

Comment: I tried  GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity providing logins as you said, showing error :{"__type":"UnrecognizedClientException","message":"The security token included in the request is invalid."}, it saying to enter valid value. Are there any string conditions for providing username(value)?

Comment: You are right about the user name.  GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity is an authenticated API, please make sure you call it from your backend with AWS Access Key and Secret Key.

Comment: I thought we need to call GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity first so we get token and IdentityId,and using that token we call AssumerolewithwebIdentity to get temeperory credentials(Access Key and Secret key), am I wrong? how to call GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity with Access Key and Secret key because we get Access Key and Secret key after calling AssumerolewithwebIdentity?

Comment: Access Key and Secret key of my account? then you saved my life.. thank you

Comment: Yes Sandesh, you should use your access key and secret key. Since this API is called from your backend, so it is secure. Your app users would get token and identityId from your backend and then exchange those via AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity or GetCredentialsForIdentity for temporary AWS credentials. Good to hear that you got it working, as always please feel free to post on our forums or here if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you sir, I know you are engineer at aws.amazon.com. Will you please look at this problem [Identiy not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417794/amazon-cognito-identity-not-found?noredirect=1#comment58717741_35417794)