# Amazon cognito: identity not found

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am working on developer authenticated project.And I am trying to get credentials using this below code.But it is giving me following error.

I have pasted IdentityId and Token manually into this code from server code:

```
    Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.ResourceNotFoundException: Identity 'ap-northeast-1:fe81cd76-e9d4-4416-99ea-b684b78743c8' not found. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 2ac65fe8-d41a-11e5-8674-677eefdb5331)
                                                 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:709)
                                                 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:385)
                                                 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:196)
                                                 at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:533)
                                                 at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:406)
                                                 at com.example.sandesh.aws.MainActivity$network.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:101)
                                                 at com.example.sandesh.aws.MainActivity$network.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:52)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
```

Here is my code: MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;

protected static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = null;
private GetCredentialsForIdentityResult credentialsForIdentityResult;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            network net = new network();
            net.execute();
        }
    });
}
public class network extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Authentication developerProvider = new Authentication(
                null,
                "ap-northeast-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1);

        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(),
                developerProvider,
                Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1);


        HashMap<String, String> loginsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        loginsMap.put(developerProvider.getProviderName(), "7386372772");
        credentialsProvider.setLogins(loginsMap);
        credentialsProvider.refresh();
        GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest credentialsForIdentityRequest = new GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest();

        credentialsForIdentityRequest.setIdentityId(developerProvider.getIdentityId());
        credentialsForIdentityRequest.setLogins(loginsMap);
        AmazonCognitoIdentityClient cognitoIdentityClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(credentialsProvider);
        credentialsForIdentityResult = cognitoIdentityClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(credentialsForIdentityRequest);

        Log.d("access_key",credentialsForIdentityResult.getCredentials().getAccessKeyId());
        return credentialsForIdentityResult.getCredentials().getAccessKeyId();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}}
```

Authentication.java

```
   public class Authentication extends AWSAbstractCognitoDeveloperIdentityProvider {


private static final String PROVIDERNAME = "login.blupinch.app";
public String response = " ";
String line = " ";
public Authentication(String accountId, String identityPoolId, Regions region) {
    super(accountId, identityPoolId, region);
}

@Override
public String getProviderName() {
    return PROVIDERNAME;
}
public String refresh() {

    setToken(null);

    if (getProviderName() != null &&
            !this.loginsMap.isEmpty() &&
            this.loginsMap.containsKey(getProviderName())) {

        update(identityId, token);
        return "eyJraWQiOiJhcC1ub3J0aGVhc3QtMTEiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1MiLCJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhcC1ub3J0aGVhc3QtMTpmZTgxY2Q3Ni1lOWQ0LTQ0MTYtOTllYS1iNjg0Yjc4NzQzYzgiLCJhdWQiOiJhcC1ub3J0aGVhc3QtMTphODcxZmE1Zi0yM2EyLTQ4MGQtYmFhNi1iNGVkMzE0MzcyNDQilCJhbXIiOlsiYXV0aGVudGljYXRlZCIsImxvZ2luLmJsdXBpbmNoLmFwcCIsImxvZ2luLmJsdXBpbmNoLmFwcDphcC1ub3J0aGVhc3QtMTphODcxZmE1Zi0yM2EyLTQ4MGQtYmFhNi1iNGVkMzE0MzcyNDQ6NzM4NjM3Mjg3MiJdLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2NvZ25pdG8taWRlbnRpdHkuYW1hem9uYXdzLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTQ1NTU5NTM5NywiaWF0IjoxNDU1NTU5Mzk3fQ.fHHH6aeCn5EaJGxGD6tw7bWyQpPHuYcW8SZLRGVn-3cbamJrWEPmUnNvcLJ-D6nL8AvMQy7-s1LGQ5MNaiuIH7QF6W8aWt2OMALmA_Y7eqpGQ6iQXVma_jTZSpiyBe2cPNggWgeslPtFxomwE90vW0rzS1sY3D5Y3UbnrIHNdiPKIzzP9JaQo1IsTJMKEpQM-jzWP6stV1radDuIzWQroBVQseOQSD-MXV_-cgWWSx0eQmtFbjJW6RP_nACgh0uTbGmMuOi2iKXKQAdGlYWO-PHlShbiHT-WLQoZNWuh95Hh9dMldv-mNdnYSblqYyqptLA3kObioI08XXkTqwaaAw";


    } else {
        this.getIdentityId();
        return null;
    }
}
public String getIdentityId() {

    identityId = "ap-northeast-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    if (identityId == null) {


        if (getProviderName() != null && !this.loginsMap.isEmpty()
                && this.loginsMap.containsKey(getProviderName())) {

            update(identityId, token);
            return "ap-northeast-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

        } else {
            return super.getIdentityId();
        }

    } else {
        return identityId;
    }

}}
```

I have tried it in PHP where I performed getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity , stsClient and AssumerolewithWebIdentity to get credentials it worked great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any ideas why it is showing error?

Comment: What's your use case for calling GetCredentialsForIdentity manually? The credentials provider will do that for you. In fact, the refresh() call you make already has. You should just be able to pass the credentials provider into the client you need. Is that the call that was failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Developer Authenticated Identities, the logins map for the call [GetCredentialsForIdentity](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2323YHCM0I7OO/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-4-Enhanced-Flow) should have "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com" as the key instead of developer provider name.

Also, you should not be calling this method yourself, the SDK will take care of this.

Update:

When calling getCredentialsForIdentity, in the logins map, when key is "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com", the value should be the token you got from your backend after calling GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity. You do not need to get the credentials for doing AWS operations, just initialize the AWS Service Client with this credentials provider and you should be good to go.

Comment: Are you saying about calling GetCredentialsForIdentity in this line  cognitoIdentityClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(credentialsForIdentityRequest);  If yes, Then how to retreive those credentials from cogntioidentityClient from above code?

Comment: And the loginmap above should be like this loginsMap.put("cognito-identity.amazonaws.com", "7386372772"); right? and also in the class AwsabstractcognitodeveloperIdentityprovider do I need to put my developer name  "login.blupinch.app"?

Comment: As you suggested , I have tried providing cognito-identity.amazonaws.com as key in logins. it is throwing me error saying that token you provided is incorrect. I tried with providername in cognito i created. and did not try to print the credentials but passed that to a s3 client and tried to upload file into s3. Amazingly, It worked. File got uploaded. Don't know really in what way i should understand this. Please help

Comment: Are you providing the correct token from your backend, which you get by calling GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity? Also if you have a requestId, I can dig deeper. 
For the case when it worked, can you please check whether it created authenticated or unauthenticated identity? You can check this is the Amazon Cognito Console.

Comment: I am sure I have provided correct token. And it is creating Authenticated identity. I checked that in AWS console

Comment: I can give you my aws.amazon.com login details and code If you want. Please check. Shall I give my details?

Comment: No please do not share credentials, instead you can PM me your identity pool Id. Also have you looked at Mark's reply?

Comment: Everything is fine. I followed them as Mark said, infact I knew them already. I just want to test my application. The Mistake i did was calling Getcredentials manually. Now what I want to know is  which key should i need to put in logins. cognito-identity.amazonaws.com as key giving me error. but If I replace it with my provider name it is working.

Comment: Provide your Email. Or anything so i can send you the pool ID. Thank you

Comment: You can post your question in Amazon Cognito Forums, from there you can send private messages also. Sorry, we are not allowed to share email information publicly.

Comment: Problem Solved: Two mistakes I did. Although I have changed loginsmap to "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com" I forgot to change values to token. next is I have not changed getprovidername to "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com".But it is till working the way it should not be done as I commented above.I know you will look after that. Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

(1) In your application, you do not need to call GetCredentialsForIdentity, the CredentialsProvider does all of this for you. (And ensures the correct arguments are passed in).
--> You can test that you are getting credentials by making a call to another service that requires credentials (ex S3) 
--> Another option is to call getCredentials() on the Credentials Provider and validate that an exception is not thrown

(2) In Authentication.java, refresh, you seem to be using a hard coded token? This is likely expired, and you should make sure to get new ones. (If you are just testing app side, make sure you hard code a fresh one).

(3)  In Authentication.java, refresh, it looks like you are calling update with a null token.

(4) Also make sure you are getting tokens for the hard coded identity you are using. (Again, you should only be hard coding this if you are testing).